# No contact listed on Skype: what could the issue be?

Tags: windows-7, skype

After launching Skype, I notice that my list of contacts is empty:

[image]

[image]

What could  the issue be? (I did check in and of the device that my contacts had not been removed)

I use Skype on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the folder account on "C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Roaming\Skype\" and login again.

The problem could be than there is a issues with the contact list on the local drive (corruption, ...) and it can't be read. By removing this folder and login again, it will create this folder again with data come from skype server.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: The problem could be than there is a issues with the contact list on the local drive (corruption, ...) and it can't be read. By removing this folder and login again, it will create this folder again with data come from skype server.

Comment: That is useful to know- it's worth [editing your answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1193507/edit) to include that :)